# Constraint in storyboard : dynamic value for space between to view

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I try to manage the y position of my view according to my tableview height.
See the image below :

[image: What I wish to see on the simulator]

As you can see I have defined a top-space constraint between my red view and my table view which is equals to 16.

However when I launch my ViewController this constraint is not respected :

My tableview fits well its content because its size is dynamic.

[image: what I obtained]

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Your tableview has two rows, it doesn't mean its size decreases. Print height of tableview, then you will come to know. Table height should be changed, according to its content.

Comment: I know, but on the second image that I have posted, I use the View Hierarchy Debug tool to display the UI. So the frame that you can see around the two rows is in fact my tableview, my tableview already changes its height according content.

Comment: Could you show us you logs please. To make it more clear, change background of the whole view controller(Top views background property) from storyboard to green/orange/pink like color.